# Facebook feed dialog - customizing lower left icon/text

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you customize the text in the lower-left hand corner in the Facebook Feed Dialog, as shown in the attachment?  Or is that text part of the icon?  If so, then where do you upload the icon in Facebook?  Haven't had any luck finding directions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `actions` parameter in your Feed Dialog code to make such text appear below the icon as you have mentioned. Check out the feed dialog parameters [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params)

You have not mentioned anywhere in the question, which language are you using, but if you are using-

- Javascript SDK-

  ```
  actions: {
     name: 'Join dropbox',
     link: 'http://url.com'
  }
  ```
- PHP SDK-

  ```
  'actions' => json_encode( array(
     'name' => 'Join dropbox',
     'link' => 'http://url.com'
  ))
  ```

Hope that helps! :)